# Area between $y=\ln x$ and $y=e^x-e$

Tags: integration

[image]

I need to find the lower and upper limits first, right? That means I need to solve $\ln x=e^x-e$. How can I solve this?

By inspection, I can tell that x=1 is a solution, but is there a way to obtain this answer algebraically?

Comment: I think that $x=1$ is just obvious.

Comment: See my edited post. That's obvious, but how do I get the other solution?

Comment: This is the good question I am working on.

Comment: Hey Jim, are you sure about the problem? W|A seems to give a dirty answer for the other solution. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%29%3D+e%5Ex-e

Comment: @PranavArora I've just looked at the answer, and it's 0.201. The textbook said it was a non calculator question so the question was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

For the lower bound, I do not think that the solution can be expressed using elementary function. So, let us try Newton method for solving $$f(x) = e^x-e-\ln x=0$$ You probably know that, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, Newton iterates are given by $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, let us start at $x_0=0.3$. The successive iterates are $0.217090$,$0.232434$,$0.233267$,$0.233270$ which is the solution for six significant digits.